# Standardizing phone number data

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a more elegant solution for this:

```
phone_number <- function(x) {
x <- gsub("[\\() -]", "", x) 
x <- gsub("^(.{3})(.{3})(.*)","\\1-\\2-\\3", x, perl = TRUE)
}
```

This would take data like this:

```
(123) 123-1234
123-123-1234
123 123-1234
```

And produce this:

```
123-123-1234
123-123-1234
123-123-1234
```

Comment: Can you assume that you're only getting phone numbers passed in?

Comment: I've given example input and desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could do

```
gsub(".*(\\d{3}).*(\\d{3}).*(\\d+).*?", "\\1-\\2-\\3", x)
# [1] "123-123-1234" "123-123-1234" "123-123-1234"
```

assuming that we have only three groups of digits somewhere in a character and they are what we need.